# Installed Entity Framework 4.2 via Nuget but everything seems to remain the same?

Tags: entity-framework, nuget, nuget-package

I've installed EFv4.2 via Nuget but I still don't see "DbContext generator" T4 template in EDMX model, only "Entity object generator" and "Self-tracking generator" are available. It seems that there is nothing changed.
Am I missing something ? Do I need to install EFv4.1 first ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no new features. Only bug fixes.

> **EF 4.2 = Bug Fixes + Semantic Versioning**
>
> When we released ‘EF 4.1
> Update 1’ we introduced a bug that affects third party EF providers
> using a generic class for their provider factory implementation,
> things such as WrappingProviderFactory. We missed this
> during our testing and it was reported by some of our provider writers
> after we had shipped. If you hit this bug you will get a
> FileLoadException stating “The given assembly name or codebase was
> invalid”. This bug is blocking some third party providers from working
> with ‘EF 4.1 Update 1’ and the only workaround for folks using an
> affected provider is to ask them to remain on EF 4.1. Third party
> provider writers then identified some areas in EF where it was hard to
> get EF to work with their providers, so we decided to address these
> issues in the EF 4.2 release. These provider related changes will be
> the only changes between ‘EF 4.1 Update 1’ and ‘EF 4.2’.
>
> Obviously a single bug fix wouldn’t normally warrant bumping the minor
> version, but we also wanted to take the opportunity to get onto the
> semantic versioning path rather than calling the release ‘EF 4.1
> Update 2’.

Extracted from [ADO.NET Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/01/ef-4-2-released.aspx)

**Edit**

> The templates for using the DbContext API with Model First and
> Database First are now available under the “Online Templates” tab when
> “Right-Click –> Add Code Generation Item…” is selected on the EF
> Designer.

Comment: But I can't find "DbContext generator" T4 template in EDMX model. So do I need to install EF 4.1 first ?

Comment: @Sun check the edited answer. Answer for your question was there in the link I gave

Comment: Oh, I thought I should be under the "Installed templates" tab. The machine installs VS 10 doesn't have internet connection, is there a way to download it manually then put it under "Installed templates" tab ?

Comment: @JatSing that is a different problem